# How do I create a new column summing values of another column in the same df, based on one or more values being present in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, aggregate

Say I have these two dataframes:

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'text':['harrypotter, legendsandlattes', 'legendsandlattesissocool','poems','midnightlibrary','legendsandlattes'], 'views':[200,400,300,600,100]})
test1
test2 = pd.DataFrame({'title':['legendsandlattes', 'harrypotter', 'Prideandprejudice'], 'rating':[8,6, 8]})
test2
```

How do I add a column 'total views' to test2 based on whether a value of test2 appears in test1?
So I would like the column to be like this:

```
| title            | rating | total views
| legendsandlattes | 8      | 700
| harrypotter      | 6      | 200
| Prideandprejudice| 8      | 0
```

And as you can see, legends and lattes and harry potter appear in the same cell one time, so the number of views of that cell should be added to both the harry potter row and the legends and lattes row in test2.

So far, I did manage to add another column 'Tiktok' to say whether any value of test2 appeared (partly) in test1 (which is a tiktok dataset with hashtags) by doing this:

```
test2['tiktok'] = np.where(test2['title'].str.contains('|'.join(test1['text'])), 1, 0)
test2
```

And I feel like what I now want to do might be similar, but I'm stuck on how to change the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
# find all matching occurences of title of test2 in text column of test1
pat = '|'.join(test2['title'])
matches = test1['text'].str.findall(pat)

# Explode to convert lists of matches to individual rows
test1_ = test1.assign(text=matches).explode('text')

# Aggregate the views count per matching text
agg_views = test1_.groupby('text')['views'].sum()

# map the aggregated views count
test2['views'] = test2['title'].map(agg_views).fillna(0)
```

Details

```
print(matches)
# 0    [harrypotter, legendsandlattes]
# 1                 [legendsandlattes]
# 2                                 []
# 3                                 []
# 4                 [legendsandlattes]
# Name: text, dtype: object


print(test1_)
#                text  views
# 0       harrypotter    200
# 0  legendsandlattes    200
# 1  legendsandlattes    400
# 2               NaN    300
# 3               NaN    600
# 4  legendsandlattes    100

print(agg_views)
# text
# harrypotter         200
# legendsandlattes    700
# Name: views, dtype: int64
```

##### Result

```
               title  rating  views
0   legendsandlattes       8  700.0
1        harrypotter       6  200.0
2  Prideandprejudice       8    0.0
```